# Macro running slowly

Tags: vba, excel

I had a simple macro that used to run in a minute. But it's now running very slowly. It takes about an hour to run. Is this because of the loop I'm using? Can someone help me see what went wrong?

```
Sub Runtable()

Sheets("RateTable").Cells(1, "A") = "ID"
Sheets("RateTable").Cells(1, "B") = "Section"
Sheets("RateTable").Cells(1, "C") = "Gender"
Sheets("RateTable").Cells(1, "D") = "Age"
        ' 
LastID = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 22)
For ID = 0 To LastID

LastSet = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 19)
For myRow = 2 To LastSet
Sheets("RateTable").Cells(ID * (LastSet - 1) + myRow, 1) = Sheets("Input").Cells(ID + 2, 1)
 Next myRow
Next ID
    '
Dim myMyRow As Long
Dim OutputMyRow As Long
OutputMyRow = 2

LastID = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 22)
LastSection = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 21)
LastAge = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 20)
For ID = 0 To LastID
For Section = 0 To LastSection
For myMyRow = 2 To LastAge
Sheets("RateTable").Cells(OutputMyRow, 2).Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(Section - FirstID + 2, "N").Value

OutputMyRow = OutputMyRow + 1

Next myMyRow
Next Section
Next ID

    '
 EndGenderLoop = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 23)
 For myRow = 2 To EndGenderLoop
 Sheets("RateTable").Cells(myRow, 3) = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 17)
 Next myRow
    '
EndAgeLoop = Sheets("Input").Cells(2, 24)
For AgeCurve = 0 To EndAgeLoop
    '
For myRow = 2 To 52
Sheets("RateTable").Cells(AgeCurve * 51 + myRow, 4) = Sheets("Input").Cells(myRow, 10)
Next myRow
Next AgeCurve
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn off the calculations and disable events and screen updating at the beginning, the make sure to turn everything back on at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use a status bar to determine where the code is slowing down.  [Here's one site with simple code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=87) (included below in case that link fails) but there are many others. For code this simple to be running 60 times slower now compared to earlier could indicate something wrong with the computer. Have you restarted? Can you revert to a previous backup state?

```
Option Explicit 

Sub StatusBar() 

    Dim x               As Integer 
    Dim MyTimer         As Double 

     'Change this loop as needed.
    For x = 1 To 250 

         'Dummy Loop here just to waste time.
         'Replace this loop with your actual code.
        MyTimer = Timer 
        Do 
        Loop While Timer - MyTimer < 0.03 

        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & x & " of 250: " & Format(x / 250, "Percent") 
        DoEvents 

    Next x 

    Application.StatusBar = False 

End Sub
```